# Automatically convert a word into hashtag when selected inside a textarea of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have a textarea in my html form and I want to make it that when a user selects a word inside that textarea it automatically is marked as a hashtag (so the # sign is appended in the front) and is converted to a hashtag that already exists, if it's close to it.

What would be the code I need to implement this?

1. "Catch" that a word was selected (e.g. "trains");
2. Look it up in the DB of hashtags ("trains" doesn't exist, but "train" does);
3. If found something similar (e.g. singular instead of plural) change
   the word to that (trains -> train);
4. Append a hashtag in front of the word (#train);

I can do the steps 2-3 myself, but I'm curious about the steps 1 and 4.

Thank you!

*PS: Also, on a related note, I guess I better use a DIV as my textarea and make a hidden textarea inside the form where I can copy content the user typed in, just to have more flexibility manipulating the look of it, right?*

Comment: check this out for your first step http://jsfiddle.net/NjW5a/3/

Comment: and for appending a character in front of that word you can use text.replace("#" + text)

Comment: Hey @VolkanUlukut I did what you suggested and after some more fiddling it worked. Maybe you could post an answer with my updated version so I can thank you? And thank you again! http://jsfiddle.net/HB2na/1/

Comment: nice work :) added the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to append a character in front of that word you can use text.replace("#" + text).
to get the selected text you need to use a cross browser solution. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB2na/1/)

```
var getSelected = function(){
    var t = '';
    if(window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if(document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if(document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$("#myElement").select(function(eventObject) {
    var selectedText = getSelected().toString();
    var statementReplace = $("#myElement").val();
    var replacedString = statementReplace.replace(selectedText,"#" + selectedText);
    $("#myElement").val(replacedString);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [jQuery MentionsInput](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/). **`jquery.mentionsInput`** is a small, but awesome UI component that allows you to "@mention" someone in a text message, just like you are used to on Facebook or Twitter.

It is very simple to integrate:

1. Add a script reference to jquery.mentionsInput.js:

   ```
   <script src='jquery.mentionsInput.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   ```
2. Add a bit of markup:

   ```
   <textarea class='mention'>
   ```
3. Initialise the mentionsInput:

   ```
   $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({
     onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {
       var data = [
         { id:1, name:'Kenneth Auchenberg', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' },
         { id:2, name:'Jon Froda', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' },
         { id:3, name:'Anders Pollas', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' },
         { id:4, name:'Kasper Hulthin', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' },
         { id:5, name:'Andreas Haugstrup', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' },
         { id:6, name:'Pete Lacey', 'avatar':'http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif', 'type':'contact' }
       ];

       data = _.filter(data, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });

       callback.call(this, data);
     }
   });
   ```

You are Done!